# MO diagram of Zundel cation

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

Here is the structure of the Zundel cation (courtesy Wikipedia):

[image]

The outermost shell electron count is $16$.

May I have the MO diagram of this cation?

This seems very complicated so I don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, drawing a MO diagram is only possible for two entities.
That being said, I will attempt to show you the MOs and order them according to their energy.

At PBE0-D3/def2-TZVPD, using NWChem 6.6, I found the following minimum geometry (vacuum):

[image: Charges and geometry]

**Figure 1**: Minimum geometry found for Zundel cation ($\ce{[H2O...H...OH2]^{+1}}$) with natural atomic charges, angles (in degrees) and distances (in angstrom)

MOs 1 and 2 correspond to $\ce{1s^2}$ core electrons on oxygen and orbitals 3-10 give us the states for the 8 remaining valence electron pairs.
MO 11 is the lowest unoccupied molecular orbital.

[image: MO diagram]

**Figure 2**: Molecular orbital diagram for structure from **Figure 1** at PBE0-D3/def2-TZVPD

Since the structure has no symmetry, no symmetry was assigned to any MO and the diagram above has simple labels only.
Energies (in hartree) can be found further below.

---

Below are images of each MO:

[image: MO 3]

**Figure 3**: MO #3 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 4]

**Figure 4**: MO #4 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 5]

**Figure 5**: MO #5 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 6]

**Figure 6**: MO #6 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 7]

**Figure 7**: MO #7 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 8]

**Figure 8**: MO #8 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 9]

**Figure 9**: MO #9 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 10]

**Figure 10**: MO #10 (cutoff 0.04)

[image: MO 11]

**Figure 11**: MO #11 (cutoff 0.4)

---

As a side note, we may obtain a finer view of the MOs by representing them as linear combinations of natural bonding orbitals (NBOs):

```
CMO: NBO Analysis of Canonical Molecular Orbitals

Leading (> 5%) NBO Contributions to Molecular Orbitals
======================================================
 MO   3 (occ): orbital energy =  -1.356442 a.u.
               0.426*[  5]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 7
               0.400*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
              -0.399*[  2]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 3
               0.396*[  4]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 6
               0.396*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
               0.336*[  9]: LP ( 2) O 1(lp)
 MO   4 (occ): orbital energy =  -1.327547 a.u.
               0.444*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
              -0.440*[  2]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 3
              -0.437*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
              -0.434*[  4]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 6
               0.280*[  9]: LP ( 2) O 1(lp)
              -0.272*[  5]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 7
 MO   5 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.859519 a.u.
              -0.606*[  5]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 7
              -0.502*[  9]: LP ( 2) O 1(lp)
               0.369*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
               0.359*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
 MO   6 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.839700 a.u.
              -0.562*[  4]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 6
               0.511*[  2]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 3
               0.471*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
               0.425*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
 MO   7 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.838909 a.u.
               0.533*[  2]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 3
               0.514*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
               0.481*[  4]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 6
              -0.469*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
 MO   8 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.696009 a.u.
              -0.549*[  9]: LP ( 2) O 1(lp)
               0.502*[  5]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 7
               0.302*[ 10]: LP ( 1) O 4(lp)
              -0.301*[  8]: LP ( 1) O 1(lp)
              -0.253*[  3]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 5
               0.244*[  1]: BD ( 1) O 1- H 2
              -0.227*[  4]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 6
 MO   9 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.636884 a.u.
               0.692*[ 10]: LP ( 1) O 4(lp)
               0.687*[  8]: LP ( 1) O 1(lp)
 MO  10 (occ): orbital energy =  -0.623778 a.u.
              -0.620*[  8]: LP ( 1) O 1(lp)
               0.614*[ 10]: LP ( 1) O 4(lp)
               0.344*[  9]: LP ( 2) O 1(lp)
              -0.319*[  5]: BD ( 1) O 4- H 7
 MO  11 (vir): orbital energy =  -0.201773 a.u.
               0.263*[121]: BD*( 1) O 1- H 2*
               0.262*[123]: BD*( 1) O 4- H 5*
              -0.257*[122]: BD*( 1) O 1- H 3*
               0.257*[124]: BD*( 1) O 4- H 6*
              -0.232*[113]: RY*( 1) H 7(ry*)
```

[image: Atomic numbering]

**Figure 12**: Atomic numbering for the NBO Analysis of Canonical Molecular Orbitals above